# textbox.text to string has no value?

Tags: asp.net, string, textbox, tostring

I have the following code:

//old code

where `txt_fname` and the others are TextBox IDs. The textboxes contain strings, but when I use a method for `submit_Click` to insert the values in the DB, they are not inserted. The DB keeps the old values.

The insert method is

//old code

and i know it works because `u_date` is always inserted correctly.

Any ideas why the strings are blank?

Here is the full code for the submit button:

//old code

Comment: At what point in the LifeCycle are you doing this?

Comment: Your identifier notation (ugly prefixes) is utterly awful, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd hazard a guess that you're not utilising the `IsPostBack` property in the page load event handler, and unintentionally overwriting the value(s).

Be sure to do something like

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
  // manipulate control values only if loading
}
```

If you'd provide more information with regards to what's happening on page load we might have better luck at a diagnoses.

Comment: Hmm, it seems plausible. How do I add IsPostBack functionality on these textboxes/strings? EDIT: oh, ok thanks! I'll try

Comment: @TudorGafiuc Your `Page_Load` event, please.

Comment: @TudorGafiuc Okay; yes, wrap the page load code in the condition I provided, not the button click code.

Comment: Hmm, now the values I enter in the textbox remain in place after submit / page refresh, but the DB keeps the old entries for the strings - the date is inserted correctly.

Comment: Ooooh, I was submitting with an invalid date. Meh.
Thank you so much, Grant!